# Two different styled layered navigation blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, template, catalog, custom, layered-navigation

I am trying to use two versions of the layered navigation, the only difference being is how they're styled, on two different category pages. So far I have tried duplicating the the view.phtml from catalog\layer\ and making a new template, view-range.phtml, and then calling it in via the Custom Layout Update on the Magento(v1.9) backend using

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/layer/view-range.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

but it doesn't work! I was thinking I could change the styling using scss but wondered if it was possible to call in a new template? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can Try to achieve that first remove the block `catalog.leftnav` and add new one

```
<reference name="left">
   <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
     <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav.custom" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view-range.phtml"/>
</reference>
```